# How to properly @Autowire a component in a Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm putting together a simple Spring Boot app, and having an issue with an @Autowired field not "showing up".

My main app class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringElasticCatalogApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringElasticCatalogApi.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Repository class:

```
import com.discover.harmony.elastic.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public interface CustomerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Customer, String> {

    public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);

    public List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);

}
```

This class ("Loaders") requires an @Autowired repository field, which is NULL:

```
import com.discover.harmony.elastic.model.BusinessMetadata;
import com.discover.harmony.elastic.model.Customer;
//import com.discover.harmony.elastic.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.discover.harmony.elastic.api.CustomerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//@Configuration

@Component
public class Loaders {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void loadAll(){
        this.repository.deleteAll();
        saveCustomers();
        fetchAllCustomers();
        fetchIndividualCustomers();

    }

    private void saveCustomers() {
        this.repository.save(new Customer("Alice", "Smith"));
        this.repository.save(new Customer("Bob", "Smith"));
    }

    private void fetchAllCustomers() {
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : this.repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void fetchIndividualCustomers() {
        System.out.println("Customer found with findByFirstName('Alice'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(this.repository.findByFirstName("Alice"));

        System.out.println("Customers found with findByLastName('Smith'):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : this.repository.findByLastName("Smith")) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
    }

    private List<BusinessMetadata> getData() {
        List<BusinessMetadata> metadata = new ArrayList<>();
        metadata.add(new BusinessMetadata((long)1,"TradeLine"));
        metadata.add(new BusinessMetadata((long)2,"Credit Line"));
        metadata.add(new BusinessMetadata((long)3,"Other Line"));

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

What should I change, to make the @Autowire work as expected here?

Comment: What packages are these objects in?

Comment: Where are you using the Loaders class? Can you post that code?

Comment: Sure. Here is my repo:   https://github.com/eugene-goldberg/SpringbootCatalogApi

Comment: Enable autoconfiguration of the elastic-repos using `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories` (eg on the `SpringElasticCatalogApi` class). Then define an `elasticsearchTemplate` Bean (of type `ElasticsearchOperations`. Then you can omit the `@Component` annotation on the `CustomerRepository` class as it is picked up by convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your example is not complete on implementing the ElasticSearch. To proof this, turn your `CustomerRepository` into a class and remove `ElasticsearchRepository<Customer, String>` then everything goes fine.

What you need to do is adding a new `Configuration` class, with `@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.discover.harmony.elastic.api.CustomerRepository")` to scan the provided package for Spring Data repositories.

You can find a complete example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/).